# Git Push - Permission Denied

Tags: authentication, github, git-push

I'm new to GitHub and experimenting with my first repo. I'm using my Mac which was used by my friend for few days. Now the problem is, as I tried to push my first commit, I see an error that says -

```
remote: Permission to myUserName/repo.git denied to myFrndsUserName.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myUserName/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I understand that my friend has used his credentials earlier and those are mismatching with my credentials as I tried to push my code. In best case, I would like to replace my friend's credentials with mine and I don't have to give my username and password everytime for different repos that I create in the near future.

Can somebody help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open terminal :

Enter:  `ls -al ~/.ssh` to see if existing SSH key are present in your case may be your friend have removed your previous SSH key.

if dont have any public or private key pair or if you do not want to use those keys available you have to generate new one.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@exaple.com"
# Creates a new ssh key, using the provided email as a label
```

When you are prompted to "Enter a file which to save the key" press Enter. this accepts the default file location.

At the prompt, Type  a secure passphrase. For more info see ["Working with SSH Key"](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/)

Add SSH key to your GitHub account

Copy the SSH key to clipboard.

If your SSH key file has a different name than the example code, modify the filename to match your current setup. When copying your key, don't add any newlines or whitespace.

```
$ pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

To follow further steps [click here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/#platform-mac)

Let me know if this doesn't work out properly

Comment: I have done all these earlier - Creating an SSH Key and adding it to my GitHub account. All the steps you have mentioned above were done. Still I'm getting the same error "Permission denied".

Comment: May be you can try logging in GitHub.com using your credentials lets see if it works ? @Greenhorn

Comment: Thanks for helping... I've sorted it out myself using many references from SO. It is working.